# VS2022 + vspkg + CMake: Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: cmake

There are a few other questions that hit the same error, but I don't see any that deal with this specific configuration. In short:

- VS2022
- vcpkg
- libcurl

This seems like it should be straightforward. I have followed all the instructions for vcpkg. It results in this line:

```
CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

So far so good. I install libcurl:

```
The following packages are already installed:
    curl[core,non-http,schannel,ssl,sspi]:x64-windows -> 7.88.1#1
curl:x64-windows is already installed
```

However, after creating a fresh CMake project in VS2022 and adding:

```
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
```

I get this error. CMake fails to generate its cache. The toolchain appears to be set correctly on the command line:

```
1> Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING="C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:/xxx/Projects/Sandbox/CMakeTest/CMakeProject1/out/install/x64-debug"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\xxx\Projects\Sandbox\CMakeTest\CMakeProject1" 2>&1"
```

I'm at a bit of a loss for how to proceed if I want to continue using VS2022. Interestingly everything resolves properly in VS Code.

Comment: Further to this, VS Code IDE can find the headers, but the CMake command cannot. It is complaining that it cannot find CURL_INCLUDE_DIR. These are the relevant lines:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

include_directories (${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})

Am I just approaching this all wrong? I thought vcpkg somehow magically set up the paths to work as long as I pointed the toolchain at the right place. Do I need to explicitly set the path to curl?

Answer (score 1):

Late night mistake. Despite looking at it dozens of times, the Include path is CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS (with an S) and not CURL_INCLUDE_DIR.

I'm not actually sure how the original issue resolved itself though. It was complaining that find_package could not find CURL. It does find it now and is building successfully.